# Etiquette on freebies at work

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, morale

What's the proper etiquette on grabbing freebies around the office?  How can we draw a line between stealing/wasting resources and enjoying the treats?  I work in a tech company so free food and drinks are plenty around the workplace.  Consider the following scenarios:

- Grab a whole leftover pizza home from a working lunch
- Sign up for social events but drop out in the last minute without a good reason
- Collect all empty beer bottles to get the deposit

Any pointers and explanations are appreciated!

Comment: If people are eating the company provided food then that doesn't seem particularly toxic. Why do you want the left-over food to be there at the end of the day? Your no alcohol rule is caused by the alcohol brought into tue office by the company, which seems a little silly. But, maybe some people had a very late night and decided they deserved one of the company beers that had been lying around for a few weeks. I don't think that's a problem either...

Comment: Hey @lacampane11a, I've made a edit to the end of this post to make it seem less subjective. I hope this is ok. Please edit it again if needed.

Comment: "Any leftover pizzas or veggie & dip for some working lunch would be gone by the end of the day" - Is that a bad thing, or do you prefer that it ends up in the garbage for rodents and insects to feast on? I grew up poor, so I'll never think of throwing good food away. Your great grandparents who grew up during the Great Depression would have  understood my attitude.

Comment: There are actually three issues here - 1) many people grabbing some of the freebies each is just normal; 2) One person taking a whole pizza before anyone else has a chance at some of it, or taking all the leftover beer in one hit, is anti-social behaviour; 3) Taking money from a charity box is theft, and really should be dealt with accordingly.

Comment: @yochannah Thanks.  I've edited extensively again to fit the rules better.

Answer (score 8):

> free food & drinks at work is the norm
>
> Do my greedy co-workers make my workplace toxic by grabbing the freebies (or not) around the office?

I think you're over-reacting. Your company is providing free food for the employees. Of course they're helping themselves. Leftovers shouldn't be left overnight anyway.

It's wrong to compare this with stealing money from the money-box, which is literally theft.

Of course, running away with entire pizzas is a bit discourteous, and you should take this up with whomever is arranging for food to be delivered.

Answer (score 4):

If your *company* is the provider of the food and drink that is being taken, and is not charging its employees for it, then I don't see why you are allowing this 'problem' to bother you so much.

The only real problem you mentioned is the theft of charity contributions, but you say that that has now been taken care of.

Being able to keep a sense of proportion about what really matters and what doesn't is one of the qualities that enables people to maintain friendly and cooperative relations with their colleagues. I'd suggest you work on yours a bit more.